# Re-declaring a function in C++ class

Tags: c++

```
class arbit
    {
        int var;
        public:

        int method1();
        int method1() const;

    };
```

Why does g++ does not give warning while declaring the same function twice here ?

Answer (score 15):

Because one is `const` and the other is not. These are different overloads, with different signatures. One or the other gets called, depending on whether the object you call it on is `const`.

Example:

```
arbit x;
x.method1(); // calls the non-const version
arbit const &y = x;
y.method1(); // calls the const version
```

You should declare a method as `const` if it doesn't modify the (visible) state of the object. That allows you to hand out `const arbit` objects, and be certain¹ that someone won't accidentally modify them.

For example, you would make a function `setValue` non-`const` (because it modifies the object), but `getValue` would be `const`. So on a `const` object, you could call `getValue` but not `setValue`.

---

¹ When there's a will, there's a way, and it's called `const_cast`. But forget that I ever told you.

Comment: Yup, C++ treats the const as an overload parameter

Comment: Overloading on `const` can be very useful.  For example, check out `operator[]` in `std::vector`.

Comment: A const member function can be invoked for both const and 
and nonconst objects, whereas a nonconst member function can be invoked only for nonconst objects.
 
Now how do i call the const version of method1 function here from a non constant object x. is it const_cast , which can do the desired operation for me ?

Comment: @Amit: In real life both overloads generally do exactly the same thing. There is no need to choose yourself which one to call. The overloads only exist to propagate constness correctly (if you have a const vector, `operator[]` gives you non-modifiable references, otherwise it gives modifiable references and it is up to you what you do with the reference).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the inputs

Comment: @Amit Like @Uncle says, if a function has both a const and non-const version, they better do the same logical thing or you're just in for a world of hurt. But if you truly want the const version, you need to make the object const, via: `arbit x; static_cast<const arbit&>(x).method1();`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also overload with `volatile` modifier and a combination of the two: `const volatile`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
    void bar()                { cout << "bar()" << endl; }
    void bar() const          { cout << "bar() const" << endl; }
    void bar() volatile       { cout << "bar() volatile" << endl; }
    void bar() const volatile { cout << "bar() const volatile" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    f.bar();

    foo const f_const;
    f_const.bar();

    foo volatile f_volatile;
    f_volatile.bar();

    foo const volatile f_const_volatile;
    f_const_volatile.bar();
}
```

That will output:

```
bar()
bar() const
bar() volatile
bar() const volatile
```